# Why we need pop3 or Imap protocols?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, pop3

We need Smtp protocol because we want to send emails to another servers.
But why we need pop3 or Imap protocols to write mail servers? If i store messages in my server, can't i directly access to messages? When user wants to download last 3 messages, i'll take them from Database and send to user. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: I think only one part, i use PHPMailer ( smtp client) and FakeSMTP (smtl server in c# ) applications, and want to use openpop library, are they good? or there are other good libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why we need pop3 or Imap protocols to write mail servers?

They provide a standard way for a mail client to fetch mail from a mailbox over a network.

> If i store messages in my server, can't i directly access to messages?

Certainly. I do this all the time. My mail server stores messages in the standard Maildir format, and I read from there using a console mail client after logging in using SSH.

> When user wants to download last 3 messages, i'll take them from Database and send to user.

How will the user tell you that they want to download messages? How will you send them the messages when they do? The usual methods are IMAP and POP.

Comment: I can't upvote :) your third answer help me, i just don't think about it :) Thank you

Comment: I dont see why the mail server of the receiver cannot just push them to the user agent everytime it receives mails. Could you help me here?

Comment: @PatrickInshutiMakuba — Who says it can't? IMAP and POP just don't.

Comment: @Quentin so then if the mail server of the receiver can just send the emails to the user agent of the receiver. why do we need POP or IMAP to fetch those email for us. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @PatrickInshutiMakuba — Oh. You meant the SMTP server. SMTP doesn't either. (And since mail clients are not expected to be connected to the Internet all the time, it would get timeout errors if it tried). And if you get rid of the mailbox, then which client would you push to either? I read my email on three computers on a typical day.

Comment: @Quentin Oh i see, makes sense. Thanks :)